# Is Blender's OpenVDB cache export volume channel only?

Tags: smoke-simulation, cache

I've been exploring using Blender VDB sims and not continuing with Embergen. Right now the biggest problem I'm having is that I can't apparently export flames from Blender to the OpenVDB cache. Temperature and Density are there, but there's no Flames that respond to shader settings elsewhere like vDBs generated by Embergen do. Specifically I've tried importing VDBs from Blender and VDBs from Embergen to Daz Studio, and only the Embergen ones had flames.

Is this functionality just not there, or is there a setting that specifically governs this? I found a thread from about six months about asking a similar question, but the only answer was not useful.